# Add page number to pdf using java sevlets and itext

Tags: java, itext

I have this code
i am using html in front end and servlets and using itext library

```
            PdfWriter writer =  PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("/home/sam/Desktop/java22.pdf"));
            doc.open(); 
            writer.setPageEvent(PdfPageEventHelper);

           doc.addHeader("ss", "ss");
           doc.add(new Paragraph("Executive Summary"));
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(e1));
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

            doc.newPage();



            doc.add(new Paragraph("Project Overview"));
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(e2));

            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
            doc.newPage();
```

}

have to add page no in footer 
please do help me

Answer (score 1):

In your `PageEventHelper` implement method <strike>`onStartPage()`</strike> `onEndPage` and a pageCounter. Then access directContent to add text at bottom position.

```
int pageCount = 0;

@Override
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    PdfContentByte imp = writer.getDirectContent();
    imp.beginText();

    //Play around here and adjust to values that fit nicely on your page
    imp.setTextMatrix(65f, 30f);

    imp.showText("Page " + (++pageCount));
    //End Text
    imp.endText();
}
```

Comment: Please don't use onStartPage(). It's advised to use onEndPage()

Comment: @michaël-demey Can you give a link to where that's advised? I might have to rework some of my own implementations :-)

Comment: It's in the iText book: iText in Action 2nd Edition (chapter 5). It's also described here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-header (among many other places). I'm also an iText employee so I have it from good sources ;)